# Как передать шаблон повторяемого элемента в компонент?

Tags: angular2

Хочу передать что-то типа `ng-content` в `ngFor` внутри моего компонента. Но дело в том, что мне нужно передать повторяемый элемент в элемент, который трансклюдится. [Нашёл](//stackoverflow.com/a/32319422/4928642) нечто подобное для первого ангуляра: http://plnkr.co/edit/aZKFqPJmPlfTVRffB0Cc?p=preview.

А как это сделать на втором?

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](//stackoverflow.com/q/38466490/4928642)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38466490/4928642

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого следует использовать `ngForTemplate`:

https://plnkr.co/edit/mpuQse2QuyP7QHXL7wM1?p=preview

```
@Component({
  selector: 'foo',
  template: `
    <h1>I am foo</h1>
    <div>
      <template ngFor [ngForOf]="data" [ngForTemplate]="itemTemplate"></template>
    </div>
  `
})
export class Foo {
  @Input() data: any[];
  @ContentChild(TemplateRef) itemTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Angular 2 Systemjs start</h1>
    <foo [data]="items">
      <template let-item>
        <div>item: {{item}}</div>
      </template>
    </foo>
 `,
  directives: [Foo],
})
export class AppComponent {
    items = [1, 2, 3, 4];
}
```

Тег `template` можно заменить атрибутом:

https://plnkr.co/edit/jB4qzx9Zd3JLkyenu9f3?p=preview

```
<foo [data]="items">
   <div template="let item">item: {{item}}</div>
</foo>
```

> Каким скоупом обладает затрансклюженное содержимое?

Ему полностью доступен скоуп передающего компонента, в который добавляется переменная, прописанная в `let`. Если в том скоупе уже была такая переменная, она переопределяется. Скоуп компонента-репитера шаблону не доступен.

http://plnkr.co/edit/VzT9koNXzAx3B1qvHuJ8?p=preview

---

PS: Это дополненный перевод [ответа](//stackoverflow.com/a/38466789/4928642) от [yurzui](//stackoverflow.com/users/5485167/yurzui).